# Stop a program from adding itself to login items?

Tags: macos

I use WebEx once a month or so, and every time I open it it adds itself as a login item.  I hate behavior like that...

How do I stop it from doing this?

Comment: Specifically, why is macOS smart enough to let you know that this has happened, but not smart enough to wonder your opinion on it? Even if there were just a little option on the notification to "deny", even if it were hidden behind some sort of modifier key or hover (which for all I know it is …).